# Image & video library uploads AWS, cloud front using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to develop an web based app in .net and upload image, Files and videos to AWS using asp.net and also make these files downloadable using link to aws source.

Looking at Amazon AWS sort of confused me. with so many products.

I would appreciate how can we develop .net based app which will upload different kinds of large files to amazon aws .

We want to host this app on different Server and upload file to aws server.

Not sure where to start from of what products to look for on amazon.

Confused with cloud front, amzon buckets etc..

Comment: Cloudfront is the AWS CDN so probably not relevant for you at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-reading your question and noticing that you want to host your app externally to AWS, all you will need at this point is:

**S3 (Simple Storage Storage)**

This will host your static files - images, videos, files. Files stored in S3 can be made publically accessible via URL.

Your .NET application will make use of the [AWS S3 SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/) for interacting with your S3 bucket. This abstracts the technical details and makes it simple to CRUD files in S3.

Here's an example of the [code you'll need.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html)

**At a high level, what you'll need to do:**

1. Create Amazon AWS account
2. Create S3 bucket
3. Include AWS S3 SDK to your application
4. Deploy and test

**Authentication**

If you want to make some or all of the files in your S3 bucket public, you will create a [bucket policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html).

As your application is not going to be hosted in AWS, you will be authenticating using access keys, ensure these are protected and also ensure these are not generated from your root AWS account.

Comment: No probs, re-read your answer and noticed you're hosting app outside of AWS. Have updated answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I will mark your answer as correct as it is more in line with my question.